# Realtime database Firebase rules

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I have an app that has to get data from the database, its some coordinates, the thing is this coordinates should remain secret for everyone, but I have read that anyone with my database name or by reverse enginiring my app could get access to it and get the set of coordinates.
I have been trying different things like hashing the coordinates, the problem is I need to use those coordinates in code and I cant work with them if they are hashed.

Is there any work around to this, or I have to deal with it in a different way.

Also I would like to add, digital currency to the app, the number of coins the person has is stored inside his user key, but I need to give read and write priviledges so the app can update the amount of coins he has.

I have tried many things already, and I can't wrap my head around it, what am I missing?

This are my rules:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      "$uid": {
        ".write": "$uid === auth.uid",
        ".read": "$uid === auth.uid",
          "usuario": {
            ".validate": "
              !root.child('usernames').child(newData.val()).exists() ||
              root.child('usernames').child(newData.val()).val() == $uid"
          },
        ".validate": "!root.child('users').child($uid).exists()"
      }
    },
    "usernames":{
        ".write":"true",
        ".read" : "true",
      }
  }
}
```

The users tree has this structure:

```
$uid:
  email
  creation_date
  coins
  usuario
```

I feel like im doing something really wrong, but i cant see it.

---

I'm editing for clarity.

I have an app that gets the device coordinates and compares it with the coordinates in my database, the thing is for the device to be able to get this data it has to have reading permissions, the problem is that this coordinates need to be a secret and i have read that anyone could reverse engineer my app and get access to the coordinates without the use of my app.

How could I make this coordinates a secret?

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding what you're trying to accomplish. Can you edit your question to include a sample of the code with an operation that you want to allow, and an example of the code with an operation that you want to reject?

Comment: Whom do you want to access the co-ordinates? What are those co-ordinates? It would be nice if you share a screenshot of your database with an example and then say what do you want your users to fetch.